Как добавить ссылку в vCard с помощью библиотеки PHP QR Code
Генерирую QR код с помощью библиотеки PHP QR Code
$website = "https://мой-сайт.ru/" . $user['uname'];
include (__DIR__ . "/phpqrcode/qrlib.php");

     $QRcode = $user['qr_code'];
     $name = $user['name'];
     $phone = $user['phone'];
     $email = $user['email'];
$codeContents  = 'BEGIN:VCARD'."\n";
$codeContents .= 'VERSION:3.0'."\n";
$codeContents .= 'URL;HOME:'. $website ."\n";
$codeContents .= 'N:'.$name."\n";
$codeContents .= 'TEL;WORK;VOICE:'.$phone."\n";
$codeContents .= 'EMAIL:'.$email."\n";
$codeContents .= 'END:VCARD';

    $tempDir = 'temp/'; 
    $size = 3;
    QRcode::png($codeContents, $tempDir.$QRcode.'.png', QR_ECLEVEL_L, $size);

Создается QR код, содержащий все данные, кроме ссылки URL. Считываю код с Android 12. По итогу нужно, чтобы была возможность перехода по ссылке и сохранении ссылки на сайт в контактных данных.

Согласно документации, никакого HOME у URL нет. HOME есть только у ADR.
